# T-SQL query on how a login has access to sp_helpuser stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I've been searching for this for hours but without any success, so my problem is that i have a login in SQL Server who has access to `sp_helpuser`, but I have checked the roles and the login and can't find it granted directly.

Could you help me please to find how a login inherits `sp_helpuser`, through which role or other stored procedure?

Thank you very much

Comment: I suppose the better question is, why is it a problem the user can use `sp_helpuser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link on sp_helpuser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpuser-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

**Permissions**

Requires membership in the public role.

Information returned is subject to restrictions on access to metadata. Entities on which the principal has no permission do not appear. For more information, see [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: "Read the fabulous online documentation" almost always helps!